# View Dialog Alert with input text

Tags: android, dialog

I am a new developer and I want to build an app for a personal purpose.

I would like to receive some input when the application load up on with dialog box with textbox for input only number and 1 button "Ok".

I tried to find solutions but could not so.

Thank you for all !

Comment: Share the solutions that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Android do built in [alert dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). What you need just inflate your custom layout to create alert dialog. You don't have to add your custom button which android also provite negative(some cancel action),positive(some comfirm action),neutral(which is something work like default) button for you. Which you just need to study the link.

Comment: First of all - Thank you !
I want to create an application when the application was loaded user to enter number in pop-up window. Then will be able to open the camera and all the user has to be capture images is saved in the name of the narrator that he entered first.